# Java Json subjective pretty printing

Tags: java, json, string, syntax, gson

Using the below, my gson builder prints this:

```
try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(path + ".json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create().toJson(item, writer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(e);
    }
```

results in:

```
"dharoks": {
    "inventory": [
      {
        "id": 4718.0,
        "amount": 1.0
      },
      {
        "id": 15272.0,
        "amount": 1.0
      },
      {
        "id": 23279.0,
        "amount": 1.0
      },
      {
        "id": 23255.0,
        "amount": 1.0
      },
      {
        "id": 15272.0,
        "amount": 1.0
      },
      {
        "id": 15272.0,
        "amount": 1.0
      }
    ]
```

How can I make it so pretty-printing only prettifies certain data, i.e how can I make the result something like this:

```
"dharoks": {
    "inventory": [
      { "id": 23279.0, "amount": 1.0 },
      { "id": 23255.0, "amount": 1.0 },
      { "id": 15272.0, "amount": 1.0 },
      { "id": 15272.0, "amount": 1.0 },
    ]
```

I want only Object(id, amount) to NOT use pretty printing (with the excetion of newline), everything else should.

Comment: I doubt that this is even possible in any way except creating your own pretty printer, Which is not so difficult if you aim for specific class.